# Inno setup - relative path to ReadIni

Tags: inno-setup

How can I set relative path to ini file in ReadIni?

This works:

```
#define MyAppVersion ReadIni("C:\Users\Popov\Documents\Release\Install.ini", "Release", "VersionNumber")
```

But I want this:

```
#define MyAppVersion ReadIni("Install.ini", "Release", "VersionNumber")
```

Where Install.ini is in the inno script folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`SourcePath`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_predefinedvars.htm) predefined variable, like this:

> **SourcePath**  str. Points to the directory where the current script is located, or the My Documents directory if the script has not yet been saved.

```
#define MyAppVersion ReadIni(SourcePath + "\Install.ini", "Release", "VersionNumber")

[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
```